# Markdown and footnotes: most natural format missing?

Tags: markdown, footnotes

## Markdown and footnotes so far

I'm referring to [Markdown: Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) at daringfireball.net, which seems to be primary source for Markdown syntax.

Markdown is known to be based on already existing formatting in mails and newsgroups. In mails and newsgroup, I often see something like this for footnote and forwarded references:

```
Blah, blah [1] blah, blah.

[1] http://somesite.com/somepage.html#someanchor
```

Surprisingly, this very common format, is not part of the primary Markdown reference. It only knows something like:

```
Blah, blah [some title][id] blah, blah.

[id]: http://somesite.com/somepage.html#someanchor
```

And I have never seen any using this spontaneously in either a newsgroup or a mailing list, while the former is very common.

I could just find something called [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), which has something closer to the common spontaneous usage, while different enough:

```
Blah, blah [^id] blah, blah.

[id]: http://somesite.com/somepage.html#someanchor
```

Closer, but I still never seen anyone using this in a newsgroup or mail.

## The question

I wonder why a so much common usage is not part of the primary markdown reference, and even not part of any variant I know. If someone knows some reason for this, I'm interested in knowing this reason. On the other hand, if I just missed something, like missing a markdown variant which is of very common use and includes the in practice most natural way of writing a footnote or forwarded reference (the first one introduced in this post), then I would like to know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're a few Markdown variations or 'flavours' out there that implement footnotes (besides [Php Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#footnotes), which you mentioned). Those I'm aware of are [Pandoc's Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#footnotes), [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-8.html), [ScholarlyMarkdown](http://scholarlymarkdown.com/), and [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/features/).

I believe footnotes work this way in all of these variations:

> This is some text with a footnote.[^] And another.[^]
>
> [^]: Here is the first footnote.
>    [^]: Here is the second footnote.

Or inline:

> This is some text with a footnote.^[Here is the first footnote.] And another ^[Here is the second footnote.]

They should both render this way:

> This is some text with a footnote.<sup>1</sup> And another.<sup>2</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 1. Here is the first footnote. ↩
> 2. Here is the second footnote. ↩

You can add links to footnotes too, for instance:

> This is some text with a footnote and link.[^Here is an example of a footnote with a link at the end. [link](http://stackoverflow.com)]

Which should render like this:

> This is some text with a footnote.<sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 1. Here is an example of a footnote with a link at the end. [link](http://stackoverflow.com) ↩

Btw, if you use an editor such as *Atom* or *VSCode*, you may want to add the extension [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/issues/35). As the name indicates, it allows previewing the rendered text as you type (it supports [previewing and exporting with Pandoc](https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/#/pandoc)).

Pandoc's documentation on the matter: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#footnotes

Answer (score 8):

> ...why a so much common usage is not part of the primary markdown reference, and even not part of any variant I know.

It looks like some of it is available per [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting):

**Links**

```
Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/). Here's a
reference-style link to [Google][1]. Here's a very readable link to
[Yahoo!][yahoo].

  [1]: http://www.google.com
  [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
```

**Advanced Links**

Links can have a title attribute, which will show up on hover. Title attributes can also be added; they are helpful if the link itself is not descriptive enough to tell users where they're going.

```
Here's a [poorly-named link](http://www.google.com/ "Google").
Never write "[click here][^2]".
Visit [us][web].

  [^2]: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere
        (Advice against the phrase "click here")
  [web]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ "Programmers Stack Exchange"
```

---

Also see [Markdown footnotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes) at Meta. The page mentions [Markdown With Footnotes](http://rephrase.net/box/word/footnotes/syntax/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, although that's StackOverflow specific, and not standard Markdown. I remember I tried to contact the author of the Markdown standard about this issue, but never received an answer.